# DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given using Carbon

Tags: laravel

I am trying to change date format but unfortunately I am facing an error.

Note database column date is not accepting this format "07/15/2020", I want this format 2020-7-15.

Controller:

```
  public function issuesUpdate(Request $request,Project $project)
    {   
         if(!$request->id){
             Issue::where('project_id', $project->id)->delete();
         }else{
                Issue::where('project_id', $project->id)->whereNotIn('id', $request->id)
                ->delete();
                $date = $request->date;
                $d = Carbon::parse($date);
                $getdate= $d->format('y-m-d');
            
               foreach($request->issue as  $key=>$val){  
                    Issue::updateOrCreate(
                    ['id' => $request->id[$key]],
                    ['project_id'=>$project->id,
                    'date' =>$getdate[$key],
                    'issue_status_id'=>$request->issuestatus[$key],
                    'deadline_date' =>$request->duedate[$key],
                    'issue' =>$val
                    ]);
                } 
            }
          return redirect()->route('project');
    }
```

**return request**

```
     [
       "07/15/2020"
     ]
```

Comment: The date format of your MySQL is `YYYY-MM-DD` so need to parse it. `Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');` hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that

```
Carbon::parse(date)->format('yy-m-d');
```